# Cargar una imágen en un <div> al pulsar un botón

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**jQuery**

Dispongo de un **`<button>`** llamado "**Cargar imagen**" que debe cargar una imagen bien desde un enlace o bien desde la misma ruta del archivo `.js` y `.html`.

**¿Cómo se carga una imagen desde la misma ruta del archivo .js y .html? Con extensión `.jpg`**

**HTML**:

**JS**:

```
//Cargar una imagen al pulsar un botón (desde URL).
    $("#cargar_imagen_url").click(function(){
        $("#imagen").load('http://www.ecologiaverde.com/wp-content/2013/05/Las-mejores-razas-de-perros-para-los-ninos.jpg');
    });
```

¿Dónde está el error? ¿Cómo sería la forma para cargar la imagen desde la misma ruta del directorio, sería semejante?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prueba con esto

**JavaScript**:

```
$("#cargar").click(function() {

    var image = new Image();

    var src = 'http://www.todopaisajes.com/Imagenes/paisaje-rural-del-campo.jpg'; //Esta es la variable que contiene la url de una imagen ejemplo, luego puedes poner la que quieras
    image.src = src;

    $('#image').append(image);
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="image"></div>
<button id="cargar">Cargar</button>
```

Asegúrate de adaptarlo bien a tu código, y si no, pruébalo tal cual te lo he puesto para que veas que funciona correctamente.

**EDIT**:
Como me has pedido en el comentario, para que esto solo se permita ejecutar una vez puedes hacerlo así:

```
var perm = true; //Esta variable contendrá el  valor de true y que te permitirá cambiarla después para permitir que la acción solo sea ejecutada una vez
$("#cargar").click(function() {

    if (perm === true) { //Si es verdadera la función no fue ejecutada ninguna vez

        var image = new Image();

        var src = 'http://www.todopaisajes.com/Imagenes/paisaje-rural-del-campo.jpg';
        image.src = src;

        $('#image').append(image);
        perm=false; //Por tanto, cambiamos el estado a false
    }
});
```

**Ó**

```
var perm = true;
$("#cargar").click(function() {

    if (!perm) {return;}

        var image = new Image();

        var src = 'http://www.todopaisajes.com/Imagenes/paisaje-rural-del-campo.jpg';
        image.src = src;
        $('#image').append(image);
        perm=false;
});
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda

Comment: Cierto, funciona correctamente ya lo probé. Muchas gracias. ¿Y si quiero que sólo se reproduzca una vez, aunque pulse varias veces...?

Comment: @omaza1990 Ya he actualizado mi respuesta para hacer lo que pretendías

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Javi, entendido. ¿Se puede poner height y width al attr para las imagenes?

Comment: @omaza1990 por supuesto que se puede, simplemente tienes que usar la variable imagen y añadirle el atributo height así, `image.height = 100;` si quieres que te ayude más crea una sala de chat y te sigo ayudando.

Comment: Aún no me deja la opción de crear chat, cuando salga te digo. Ya retoqué las dimensiones de la imagen. Perfecto. Ahora mi duda es... ¿si quiere hacer referencia a un ID es #imagen y si hago referencia a una clase es .imagen no?

Comment: @omaza1990 exacto

Comment: @omaza1990 no es necesario esperar, puedes crearla tu, busca en Google crear sala en SO

Comment: buena respuesta :D pero con mi +1 te fastidié tu "666" de rep xD

Comment: ¿Y si quiero hacer un bucle en una foto cambiando de fotos? Me explico: Tengo una foto X de inicio en mi html que es un button, y al pulsar cambia esa foto por otra foto Y, y al volver a pulsar cambia por le foto X, y así sucesivamente, ¿con un if sería necesario, no?

Comment: @lois6b jaajajaj, no pasa nada :p

Comment: @omaza1990 deberias hacer una pregunta aparte

Comment: @omaza1990 si deseas que las imágenes cambien dependiendo de que se pulse un botón si, pero si quieres que se cambie la imagen periódicamente y también que la pueda cambiar a través de un botón habría que hacer más cosillas, pero eso debes intentarlo tu, no puedo hacer todo el trabajo, ;D inténtalo y si tienes dudas o algún fallo pregúntame por una sala de chat

Comment: En ello me pongo ahora mismo.

Comment: @omaza1990 suerte ;)

Comment: Gracias, abrí un nuevo hilo sobre la duda con el código que he probado.